# How do you insert subscripts and superscripts into ordinary (non-formula) text in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I know that LibreOffice Writer can facilitate subscripts and superscripts in ordinary, non-formula, text—when I copy and paste such things from Microsoft Office Word 2007 documents LibreOffice Writer manages to accommodate them. My LibreOffice Writer version is 3.6.4.

I haven't managed to find any better place to ask this question, if there is please direct me to it. I am running 12.10 if it is relevant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't forget that [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=libreoffice+subscript+superscript) is your friend.

## Keyboard Shortcut

As detailed on the [LibreOffice help site](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Making_Text_Superscript_or_Subscript):

- For superscript: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- For subscript: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: No worries mate :) Good luck with LibreOffice. If you want to learn more shortcuts, try https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer

Comment: Kinda ironic that Google took me here.

Answer (score 10):

## For a GUI solution

Use **Tools** -> **Customize...** to open the following dialogue, then navigate as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: sub/sup menu items]

Adding these will add them to the menu bars and thus give easy gui-based formatting, as opposed to a shortcut.

Comment: Great answer, mate! If I could I would accept both answers but  since I've already promised the other guy to accept his answer.

Comment: @BrentonHorne I'm in no need for accepted answers. I'm just providing an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my keyboard set to English (US, alt, intl.)

<kbd>ralt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>  then <kbd>2</kbd>  gets me ²

<kbd>ralt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>  then <kbd>2</kbd>  gets me ₂

and while I am at it:

<kbd>compose</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>3</kbd> gets me ⅔

This works in any application, including LibreOffice and the terminal.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Kubuntu 22.04 on Firefox, LibreOffice and Terminal. Superscript here², subscript here₂. You should note to, if you use two hands, release right hand press every time before pressing the number by left hand. Pressing all keys simultaneously would otherwise give you wrong character.